# how to get soft keypad to write email id in edittext in android

Tags: android

I am using android:phoneNumber to open soft keypad to get phone number in android.I want to open keypad which contains all key required to write email id in edittext.So is there any solution for this(email) like phone number.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set property **Input Type** for **EditText**

[image: Image of Input Type]

Answer (score 9):

Use **textEmailAddress** (0x00000021) as defined here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

In Java code:

```
 myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

In XML properties:

```
 android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Answer (score 2):

use the below code for getting the email soft keyboard

```
Editetxt email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edotetxtemail)
email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: For Google Android 2.3.5, at least, you actually need setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);